# How to embed powerBI Dashboard to SharePoint online? [Not individual reports]

Tags: sharepoint, powerbi, office365

How we can embed a PowerBI Dashboard in SharePoint online?

I tried the page viewer web part and embed code with and without iframe.

But it doesn't work.

I am not referring to embedding reports. That can be done using the report web part.

But this web part embeds only reports, not the dashboard.

Answer (score 0):

Currently this scenario is not supported, but you can [vote for it](https://ideas.powerbi.com/ideas/idea/?ideaid=fc3f1ad5-a2c5-4af6-a5de-1bc08e009c3a).